# Error on video play in phantomJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm using Karma, Jasmine and PhantomJS.
In one of my test I have to following line:

```
let video = this.element.find('#my-video');
video.play();
```

but it gives the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'video.play()')

When running Karma in browser there is no error, but when running in terminal the is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for `video` tag in PhantomJS.
See this [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839) on GitHub.

You can use an E2E for you test like selenium which runs on real browser, or mock the HTML element.